# Update Position Of Observable Array With New Item In Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I have a situation where I need to replace a certain item in an observable array at a certain position of it.  Right now I am doing it below with the slice method.  Is there a better way that is built in to knockout.js to do this at a certain position?  I was even thinking about doing a push, and then do a sort on that row with a order property but I have lots of rows and thought that was to much.

```
var position = ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(self.list(), game);

if (position != -1) {
   self.list.remove(self.game);
   self.list.splice(position, 0, newGame);
}
```

**Code With Replace, Trying To Update Property Matchup That Has A New Property Called Name**

```
var game = self.game;

                    if (game) {

                        var position = ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(self.list(), game);

                        if (position != -1) {

                            if (game.Matchup) {
                                game.Matchup = new Matchup(response.Data);
                                game.Modified(true);
                            }
                            else if (self.game) {
                                game = new Matchup(response.Data);
                            }

                            self.list.replace(self.list()[position], game);
                        }
                    }
```

**HTML**

```
                <!-- ko foreach: Games -->
                <td class="item-container draggable-item-container clearfix">
                    <div class="item clearfix draggable-active draggable-item" data-bind="draggableCss: { disabled: $data.Disabled(), matchup: $data.Matchup }, draggableGameHandler : { disabled: !$data.Matchup, disabledDrop: $data.Disabled() }, delegatedClick: $root.members.eventSchedule.editGame.open.bind($data, true, ($data.Matchup && $data.Matchup.Type == '@((int)ScheduleType.Pool)'), $parent.Games)">
                        <span data-bind="if: $data.Matchup">
                            <span data-bind="attr: { title: Matchup.Title }"><span data-bind="html: Matchup.Name"></span></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <!-- /ko -->
```

`data-bind="html: Matchup.Name"` doesn't update with replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Replacing an item in an observable array

The `replace` method is one option for replacing an item in an observable array. In your case, you could call it like this:

```
list.replace(game, newGame);
```

#### Bindings update when an observable dependency changes

But your question isn't only about replacing an item in an array. You've stated that the binding `html: Matchup.Name` isn't updated, so let's look at what could cause it to update:

1. If `Name` is an observable, modifying `Name` will cause an update.
2. If `Matchup` is an observable, modifying it will cause an update, but then you'd have to bind it like `Matchup().Name` and update it like `game.Matchup(Matchup(response.Data));`.
3. Replacing the entry in the observable array (is it `Games` or `list`?) with a new object will cause the whole inner template to re-render, obviously replacing each binding.

Looking through your code, I can see that in one case (`if (game.Matchup)`), none of these three things happen, and thus there's no way Knockout can know to update the binding. The first two obviously aren't occurring and although you do call `replace` on the array, it's the equivalent of this:

```
list.replace(game, game);   // replace the item with itself
```

The `foreach` binding doesn't see the above as a change and doesn't update anything. So, to update the binding, you need to make a real update to an observable.

#### Further comments

To get the index of an item in an observable array, use the `indexOf` method:

```
var position = self.list.indexOf(game);
```

To replace an item at a specific index, use the `splice` method with a second parameter of `1`:

```
self.list.splice(position, 1 /*how many to remove*/, newGame);
```

Comment: Does indexOf work in older browsers?  Dont you think that .replace should update that array?  Doesnt that make sense.

Comment: `indexOf` is part of `ko.observableArray` and works in all browsers. The `foreach` binding doesn't know that you called `replace` specifically; it just checks to see how the array has changed and doesn't find any changes.

Answer (score 1):

`Observable arrays` have a built in `.replace` method you can use to do this:

```
var position = ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(self.list(), game);

self.list.replace(self.list()[position], game);
```

Comment: Geez how did I not see that, will give it a try.

Comment: For some reason it wont update my observable array with the new item like with the remove/splice method.

Comment: This should replace the whole item in the array with the new one showing the changes in the UI.